# Load model in MY_Loader Codeigniter

Tags: model, load, codeigniter-2

How can I load a model in my MY_Loader.php -file in directory "application/core"?

Im trying to group my loader-views into a MY_Loader -file for more convenient loading of the views. I want to pass dynamic values to the header to customize the title output.

My code looks like this:

```
private $ci;   

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Initiate instance
    $this->ci =& get_instance();

    // Load model
    $this->ci->load->model('My_loader_model');

}   

public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    $data_header['inbox_messages'] = $this->ci->My_loader_model->inbox_messages_count();

    $content  = $this->view('header', $data_header, $return);
    $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
    $content .= $this->view('footer', $vars, $return);

    if ($return)
    {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can auto load models in autoload.php. Why are you making trouble doing it some where else

Comment: Have added it to $autoload['model'] = array('my_loader_model'); in autoload.php still doesn't seems to get loaded so I can integrate with it from my MY_Loader.php (in dir "core"). I've added `log_message ("debug", "Yourmodel is loaded"); ` to the models constructor to see if it gets loaded, which it doesn't get. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it to work now. Big capital in model name in autoload array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: please delete this question as you have neither an answer nor you need anymore. Or shall i add an answer for you to accept?

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 file with commondata extends of CI_Controler in core folder.
Set Common model as autoload

```
function getSettingData($id)
{
        return $this->common->selectbyid($id);
}
```

}

include this file into myLoader like this

/**
 * /application/core/MY_Loader.php
 *
 */
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader{

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    include(dirname(__FILE__)."/commondata.php");
    $settingdata = new commondata();
    $vars['companyname'] = $settingdata->getSettingData(1);
    $content = "";

        $content = $this->view('templates/header_admin', $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view('templates/footer_admin', $vars, $return);



        return $content;
}
```

}